# What best way use in Angular in my case?

Tags: angularjs

I need write some methods that works with socket.io in Angular JS.

1. SendMessage()
2. GetMessages()
3. TypingMessage();

For example, after event `ng-click="SendMessage()"` I need send message via Socket.io.

I have wrote a good tutotial in Stack overflow about service and factory Angular JS. But still can not choose right way what use in my case. Put this methods in Factory method or make service?

Comment: Why does factory/service matter here?

Comment: Because I want to use common methods `SendMessage()` from any controller

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have a look at the following git repo:

https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

I use this in combination with a Python socket server and it works great. You will be able to create your own socket factory from btford's socketFactory which you can use as a normal factory.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'btford.socket-io'
]).
factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
  var myIoSocket = io.connect('/some/path');

  mySocket = socketFactory({
    ioSocket: myIoSocket
  });

  return mySocket;
});
```

Comment: You beat me to it by a few seconds...
I would just add make sure you read the docs.  Don't forget the bit that you need in the html page

Comment: Thanks, but where to locale users methods?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'locale users methods'.